# Maximum call stack size exceeded when adding a footer to my Jade template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Ok, this is kind of wierd but here's the situation.

I'm playing about with Express and the Jade tempting system.

I have a fairly straightforward `layout.jade` file:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    h1 Nav goes here!
  body
    block content
```

and a `home.jade` file:

extends layout

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

The above combinations works fine.

But, i wanted to add a footer, so I created a `foot.jade` file:

```
extends layout

block foot
  h1= me
```

And added `include foot` to my `layout.jade` file.

Now if I try to access the home page of my app, im getting a `Maximum call stack size exceeded`error :/

My app.js file is:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , home = require('./routes/home')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home', {title: 'Ninja Store'});
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foot.jade` uses `extends layout`, which loads `layout.jade`, which has an include for `foot.jade`, which uses `extends layout`, which loads `layout.jade`, ...

In other words: remove `extends layout` from `foot.jade` ;)

Comment: Or add `block foot` to index.jade and remove `include foot`

Comment: @generalhenry if `include foot` were to be changed to `block foot`, then how would the `foot` partial get called to be rendered?